# Login page won't render in React v18

Tags: reactjs, routes

I'm having a problem with my routes in React v.18. I cannot get a login page to render.

**Index.js**

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <App/>
  </Router>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
export const App = () => (
    <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />         
        </Routes>
    </>
)
 
export default App;
```

I get this error message in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname'). And it says the error is coming from the  component. But I don't have access to change anything in the `<Router>` component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that all 'react-router-dom' related are imported properly.

ex.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
```

then try doing this to yout index.js:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

then to your App.js:

```
 <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />         
        </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Hope that helps